# Return on Capital Invested - what to include in 'capital employed'

Tags: capital-returns, capital

The formula for ROCE is:

ROCE = net profit before tax / capital employed

Where capital employed is long-term liabilities + share capital + retained profit.

However, I've only used this in very simple situations, so when I came across Samsung's financial report, I am somewhat confused (balance sheet at page 4, P&L account at page 7):

https://images.samsung.com/is/content/samsung/p5/global/ir/docs/2017_con_quarter04_all.pdf

Can I confirm that the values (in millions of Korean won) are:

Net profit before tax = 56,195,967

LTL = Total liabilities - total current liabilities = 87,260,662 - 67,175,114

Retained profit = 215,811,200

Share capital = preference shares + ordinary shares = 119,467 + 778,047

Also, should share premium be included in share capital?